# initializing yml file in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm following a basic tutorial on authentication in rails

http://jrom.net/super-simple-authentication-in-rails

The tut suggests putting a hashed password into a config.yml file, so I am following this railscast for that

http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file. This tutorial is for rails 2 so I changed the initialization to the rails 3+ format

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('/config/config.yml'))[Rails.env]
```

Right now I am having trouble with the initialization and this is the problem that i am getting

```
/Users/Yitao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:299:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /config/config.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:299:in `open'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:299:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Yitao/Documents/Business/Dental/DentistrySite/config/initializers/load_config.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Yitao/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
```

Would appreciate some advice on where I might be messing up!

Also if I were to push this to heroku, would heroku config:set username=xxxx do the trick to set the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the slash from the path to the YAML file, so change `'/config/config.yml'` to `'config/config.yml'`. With the slash on there it is looking for a config directory at the root of your drive rather than in your Rails project directory.